# trying to convert C to Lisp

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp, code-translation

I am trying to convert this code to lisp code.
But don't know how to do it
is it right?

```c
for (j=i-1; j>=0 && list[j]>key; j--) {
    list[j+1] = list[j];
}
```

```lisp
(loop (set j (- i 1))
  (setq (aref x(+ j 1) (aref x j))
  (setq j (- j 1)
  (when (or(>= j 0)
           (> (aref x j) key)
  (return-from foo 0))
```

Comment: Learn loop here: [Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html), [udemy course (free video in the iteration chapter)](https://www.udemy.com/course/common-lisp-programming/).

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is to use the extended `loop`:

```lisp
(loop :for j :downfrom (1- i)
      :while (and (not (minusp j))
                  (> (aref list j) key))
      :do (setf (aref list (1+ j))
                (aref list j)))
```

(Note: I prefer to use keywords for loop keywords, because that gives me nice syntax highlighting for free.  You will often also find them as plain symbols, e. g. `for` instead of `:for`.)

Comment: thx for advice :)

Answer (score 3):

though it's not a word-by-word translation, i would probably go with something like this:

```
(let* ((data (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
       (key 3)
       (pos (or (position-if (lambda (x) (<= x key)) data :from-end t)
                0)))
  (setf (subseq data (1+ pos))
        (subseq data pos))
  data)
```

Looks more like a CL style to me.